# Would this be an acceptable answer for the inverse of floor function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

[image]

And the  book's definition on inverse

[image]

Would an acceptable answer to 43b just be the set itself again? What I like to think of the inverse is what input did you pass to get this output. One can pass {-1, 0, 1} into the floor function to get {-1, 0, 1}. Is this the right way to think about this problem? Or is it better to introduce 3 separate variables, say x, y, and z and show the interval of values that can be passed into the floor function to get this set.

Comment: With the definition saying "the unique element", I would say the floor function doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: good catch. I didn't see that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overloading here, of the symbol $f^{-1}$.

If $R$ is a binary relation, then $R^{-1}=\{(a,b)\mid (b,a)\in R\}$, and when $f$ is an injective function we can show that $f^{-1}$ is an injective function as well (here a function is just a set of ordered pairs with a particular property). In the case we call $f^{-1}$ the inverse function.

But if $f$ is not an injective function then $f^{-1}$ is not a function, it is a binary relation. In that case we use $f^{-1}$ to denote the *preimage* function, which is a function mapping subsets of the range (or codomain) to subsets of the domain. Namely, $f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in A\}$.

Note, that if $f$ is indeed injective, then for every singleton, $\{b\}$ its preimage is at most a $\{a\}$ for some $a$ in the domain.

You are asked to find the preimage, which is the set of *all* values being mapped into the given set. So writing $g^{-1}(\{-1,0,1\})=\{-1,0,1\}$ is blatantly wrong, since there are many numbers being mapped to those three values, not just the three.

Comment: g is not an injective function because there are multiple values from set R that will map to one value in Z? (0.2, 0.3, and 0.4) are all values from set R that will map to one value in Z, 1?

Comment: That is correct, although the values that you suggested all map to $0$, this is the floor function.

Comment: But by definition of inverse function, would the floor function not have an inverse function then, because of this line "The inverse function of is the function that assigns to an element b belonging to B, the unique element a in A such that f(a) = b. For a b like -1, there are multiple elements in A that the floor function can map it to - -0.5, -0.1, -0.3, etc....

Answer (score 0):

You are right that $-1, 0,$ and $1$ are themselves solutions. And your intuitive definition of the inverse is also correct, so you do not need to introduce three variables.

Rephrasing your intuition, just imagine which real numbers $x$ when plugged-in to the floor function will output either $-1, 0,$ or $1$.

For instance, $1.1$ is mapped to $1$. And so are $1.0001, 1.23.$ and $1.999$.

Similarly, $-0.5$ is mapped to $-1$. And so are $-0.01$ and $-0.9999$.

Can you now see the pattern?

Comment: wouldn't there have to be three values in the set though. Because to get to a set of three elements, you need to pass in a set of three elements? I don't get your either -1, 0, or 1 intuition.

Comment: Not necessarily. Remember that a function can be one-to-one OR many-to-one. It's the latter in this case.

Comment: oh so the question is asking what input can be passed into the floor function to get -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Mark, I think the trick is what Henrik pointed out, the floor function doesn't have an inverse because it doesn't meet the definition of unique element a.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the questions is not asking about the inverse, but rather the preimage. Not only would this allow the question to be well defined, it would also explain why they wrote $g^{-1}(\{0\})$, instead of $g^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Isn't preimage like the same thing though. I read from my book that if f(a) = b, a is the preimage of b. Inverse is to map to pre image?

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\f}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}
g(x)=\f x$$
Now if:
$$g^{-1}(x)=y$$
This would make sense that:
$$\f y=x$$
So:
$$g^{-1}(\{0\})=k\implies \f k=0\implies k\in[0,1)$$
If 
$$g^{-1}(\{-1,0,1\})=k\implies \f k\in{-1,0,1}\implies k\in[-1,2)$$
And:
$$g^{-1}(\{x\mid0<x<1\})=??$$
Last one is a good question.

Comment: Last one is a good question because there is no inverse :)