# Simplistic Odd Collatz formulas

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, collatz-conjecture

I've been experimenting with the Collatz for a couple of months. 
I just want to give you some formulas and show tables that give the same results for odd inputs. I have also several new functions, but ill only provide a few of them here. I tweaked the formulas. It seems very strange that all of them give the same outputs. My notes are a bit messy, so bear with me if I didnt provide all the details.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
n  & 3n & 3n+1 & \frac{3n+1}{2} \\ \hline
1  & 3  & 4  & 2  \\ \hline
3  & 9  & 10 & 5  \\ \hline
5  & 15 & 16 & 8  \\ \hline
7  & 21 & 22 & 11 \\ \hline
9  & 27 & 28 & 14 \\ \hline
11 & 33 & 34 & 17 \\ \hline
13 & 39 & 40 & 20 \\ \hline
\end{array} *orginal collatz formula, dividing by two.*

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
n  & 2n & \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor & 2n-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor \\ \hline
1  & 2  & 0 & 2  \\ \hline
3  & 6  & 1 & 5  \\ \hline
5  & 10 & 2 & 8  \\ \hline
7  & 14 & 3 & 11 \\ \hline
9  & 18 & 4 & 14 \\ \hline
11 & 22 & 5 & 17 \\ \hline
13 & 26 & 6 & 20 \\ \hline
\end{array} *a new(?) formula.*

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
n  & \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor & n+1 & \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + n+1 \\ \hline
1  & 0 & 2  & 2  \\ \hline
3  & 1 & 4  & 5  \\ \hline
5  & 2 & 6  & 8  \\ \hline
7  & 3 & 8  & 11 \\ \hline
9  & 4 & 10 & 14 \\ \hline
11 & 5 & 12 & 17 \\ \hline
13 & 6 & 14 & 20 \\ \hline
\end{array} *yet another.*

Here $n$ is a positive integer. The floor function omits the fractional part if the result is real.

The functions from the tables above:

$f(n) = \frac{3n+1}{2}$

$f(n) = 2n-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

$f(n) = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + n+1$

The latter formula is the one i've been working on lately.
We can change it again,
$\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+n+1 = \frac{n}{2}+\frac{2n}{2}+\frac{2}{2} = \frac{3n+2}{2}=\lfloor\frac{3n}{2}\rfloor+1$.

That gets us back to the formula in the first table. They look quite similar.

The function
$f(n) = 2n-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$
is also quite interesting. In a "geometric" standpoint we can look at it like doubling the $n$ and then removing the half of the total, here's a simple figure showing this:

[image]

I have never seen this formula before, and wonder if I can use this notation:

$f(n)=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+\begin{cases} n+1 & n\equiv 1\pmod2 \\ 0 & n\equiv 0\pmod2 \end{cases}$

See, for odd and even we can halve the input in one go. And then add the result of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using an alternate form of the original Collatz ($3x+1$) rule, as long as you have a reason for the modification.

Without using a floor function, it is much easier to show that your method is equivalent to the $\frac{(3n+1)}{2}$ rule. The floor function truncates 0.5 after dividing an odd integer in half, therefore removing 1 from the odd integer in the first place and then dividing by 2 will provide the same effect. (ex. $\lfloor$9/2$\rfloor$ = 4.5 - 0.5 = 4, and (9-1)/2 = 4.)

With that in mind, here is a proof to validate your method:

$\frac{n-1}{2}$ + $n$ + $1$

= $\frac{n-1}{2}$ + $2n\over2$ + $2\over2$

= $\frac{n - 1 + 2n + 2}{2}$

= $\frac{n + 2n + (-1) + 2}{2}$

= $\frac{3n+1}{2}$

The expressions $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ + $n$ + $1$ are equivalent.

Comment: You don't prove something by deducing a true conclusion from an assumption that it's true. A correct way to prove what you claim here is to delete the word "Assume", delete the left sides of the equations and delete the equals sign on the first line. Then you will have shown that the expression on the right in the first line is equal to $(3n+1)/2$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for your feedback. I created the proof to the best of my knowledge, and I did not have the proper mindset for a correct proof.

Comment: OK now you're learning. You can put back the equal signs starting on the second line.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for helping me. I regret assuming the trig identity problems in a pre-calculus class implied any formal proof notation.

Comment: This looks quite similar to the expressions in my original post, except that you've included $-1$. So is it just the inclusion of $-1$ that is the magic thing here? And removing the floor function to actually prove that they are equal?

Comment: When I made the proof, I did not have the floor function in mind. However, using the floor function in this case produces the same effect. The only time the floor function is needed is when $n$ $\equiv$ 1 (mod 2), and the floor function always truncates 0.5 from the result. Since 0.5 * 2 = 1, removing 1 in the first place guarantees the division of a 0 (mod 2) number, and the resulting answer will always be an integer.

Comment: I looked into the inverse for a floor function and there does not seem to be one. This topic goes beyond my knowledge, so I found some links that may give a deeper insight to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107576/would-this-be-an-acceptable-answer-for-the-inverse-of-floor-function https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/inverse-floor-function.323583/

Comment: Lastly, I am sorry for not recognizing your use of the floor function in the first place. I edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's nothing strange going on here: these formulas are all equivalent. (Can you prove it?)
**Hint:** if $n$ is odd then $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: No I can't. But I think that since integers in general don't have a fractional part the floor function does remove this, and so in binary form the parity of the bits are changed due to the behaviour of some of these functions.

Comment: See if you can prove they're equivalent! Hint: $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even, and $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2} \not\in\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Sure, but if $n$ is odd, then $\frac{n}{2}\not\in \mathbb{Z}$ as well. When you subtract off $\frac{1}{2}$, you *do* get an integer.

Comment: Aha, I see. For a different. I like to look at the numbers in binary. For $f(n) = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+n+1$ in binary this example shows in more detail whats going on: $1011101_2$ $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ is basically just shifthing the bits to the right, giving: $101110_2$, we can now choose either add $1$ or $n$. adding $1$ we get $101111_2$ but if the second least significant bit was even this parity would have been different. now we can add the whole $n$. Anyways, I have a feeling the complexity of this computation of odd number could provide details of how the function progresses.

Comment: Good luck, and I hope you learn something from it!

Comment: The OP said "I wonder if I can do this", and I said "sure". That seems like an answer to me.

Comment: I strongly recommend you edit your answer to incorporate at least one of your comments.

Comment: I am happy to accept your recommendation, provided you can tell me what question of the OP I failed to address in my answer but did address in my comments.